# Cufon always render as bold

Tags: html, css, cufon

I'm made a Cufon font for a new website I'm working on. However even though I've included both a normal and a bold version of the font when I made it, it always renders as bold text.

I use it for my H1, H2 etc. tags, but I've tried applying it to a simple P tag as well - same problem :-(

Any ideas what might cause this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your CSS specify that the font should be bold?

Comment: No, quite the contrary actually. I've even tried inlining "font-weight: normal"; to no avail :-(  I can only get it to work by leaving the bold version out of the generated Cufon, which unfortunately isn't an option.

Comment: Quite strange. My experience with Cufon is quite limited so I'm guessing now but.... have you tried specifically passing the option to Cufon? eg. Cufon.replace('h1', {fontWeight: 'normal'});

Comment: Thanks for the tip, reading up on font-weights I found out my font in question is only 300, which is below normal. Using font-weight: 300 in my css solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check two things in the font file (i.e. "TradeGothic_LT_CondEighteen_500-TradeGothic_LT_CondEighteen_500.font.js"):

```
Cufon.registerFont({"w":159,"face":{"font-family":"TradeGothic-Normal","font-weight":500,....
Cufon.registerFont({"w":159,"face":{"font-family":"TradeGothic-Bold","font-weight":500,....
```

The above is an invalid font file because the font names are different.  To use the bold/normal dynamic, both must be in the same font-family.  Additionally, one must have a heavier font-weight, or cufon cannot decide which is bold.

The fixed version of the font file is below:

```
Cufon.registerFont({"w":159,"face":{"font-family":"TradeGothic","font-weight":500,....
Cufon.registerFont({"w":159,"face":{"font-family":"TradeGothic","font-weight":700,....
```

Comment: This fixed my issue -- different font faces mean the Cufon.replace() call always refers to the most recently defined font. In this case, Bold (or Italic, or Bold Italic, if they're defined)